# CF keyDown event (timed)

Tags: compact-framework

I need an event for my CF application, that would trigger after user has pressed an held his finger on the control for 2 seconds. What event can i use, since keyDown event is already used.

Comment: yes, thak you for reminding me ! Im so much into learning C# and all the frameworks i completely forgot to accept anwsers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, KeyDown is pretty irrelevant for capturing the length of time a finger is pressed. The use of the finger relates to the events `Click`, `MouseDown`, `MouseUp` and `MouseMove`.

To get the behaviour you're after, the events you should be interested in are `MouseDown` and `MouseUp`.

I suggest the best way to do this would be to create your own control base class. Here's one I made earlier (not tested, but should give you a general idea of what to do):

```
public partial class BaseControl : UserControl
{
    public BaseControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        base.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(BaseControl_MouseDown);
        base.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(BaseControl_MouseUp);

        MouseHeldTimer = new Timer();
        MouseHeldTimer.Interval = 2000;
        MouseHeldTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(mouseHeldTimer_Tick);

    }

    protected Timer MouseHeldTimer;
    protected bool MouseIsDown;

    void mouseHeldTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.MouseHeldTimer.Enabled = false;
        if (this.MouseHeldDown != null)
        {
            this.MouseHeldDown(sender, e);
        }
    }

    void BaseControl_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        this.MouseHeldTimer.Enabled = true;
    }

    void BaseControl_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        this.MouseHeldTimer.Enabled = false;
    }

    public event MouseHeldDownHandler MouseHeldDown;
    public delegate void MouseHeldDownHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);

}
```

Basically, the MouseHeldTimer will start with an interval of 2 seconds the moment the user touches their finger to the screen. If the user lifts their finger the timer is stopped. If the user's finger is down for longer than 2 seconds, the delegate event `MouseHeldDown` will fire. You can then capture this event on your form by doing the following:

```
control.MouseHeldDown+= new EventHandler(control_MouseHeldDown);
```

Alternatively, if you only care about the form, you can just use the Form's `DoubleClick` event as that will fire after holding the mouse down for a second or two.

Comment: thanx for the anwser. Yes, i made a mistake and wrote key instead of mouse. Your solution works perfectly.